# Functions not running when called through HammerJS

Tags: angular, typescript, hammer.js

I have a component that shows information for days that are cycled through with functions `dayUp()` and `dayDown()`. They both look like the following:

```
  dayUp() {
    if (this.dayCount == 7) {
      return;
    }
    this.dayCount++;
    if (this.dayCount == 0) {
      this.today = 'Today'
    } else if (this.dayCount == 1) {
      this.today = 'Tomorrow'
    } else if (this.dayCount == -1) {
      this.today = 'Yesterday'
    } else {
      this.today = '';
    }
    this.getSelectedDay(this.dayCount);
  }
```

I am calling these functions with buttons for each one. They work as expected and updates the view with the new information accordingly. I am tying to add swipe functionality to do the same thing with gestures using HammerJS. I have it set up and the swipes are working with the correct directions. I have a console log to test. I have the `dayDown()` set to swipe left and `dayUp()` set to swipe right. I can tell from the debugger that they are both indeed being called correctly and the function is running and changing the value of the `dayCount` variable. The issue is that the view is not updating or responding at all like it does when the functions are called from the button. To be clear, I am calling the same exact function with the button as well as the swipe. The buttons work as expected but they are not working when called through the swipe. I'm not sure what is causing this. The HammerJS code is below:

```
    const switcher = document.getElementById('switcher');
    var mc = new hammer(switcher);
    mc.on('swipeleft', () => {
      console.log('left');
      this.dayDown();
    });
    mc.on('swiperight', () => {
      console.log('right');
      this.dayUp();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

You can also try to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and put `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` in the callback functions after calling your own functions

```
private @ViewChild("myDiv") myBtn: ElementRef;

constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef){}

myFunction() {
  const switcher = this.myBtn.nativeElement;
  var mc = new hammer(switcher);
  mc.on('swipeleft', () => {
    console.log('left');
    this.dayDown();
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
  });
  mc.on('swiperight', () => {
    console.log('right');
    this.dayUp();
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
  });
}
```

---

### Old Answer

You need to run the code inside the [ngZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone) so as the variables are being changed outside the Angular scope as they are callbacks for the Hammerjs APIs.

The other thing that it is always better to access the DOM elements using the ViewChild instead of directly access it using the getElementById, querySelector ...etc

```
private @ViewChild("myDiv") myBtn: ElementRef;

constructor(private zone: NgZone){}

myFunction() {
  this.zone.run(_ => {
    const switcher = this.myBtn.nativeElement;
    var mc = new hammer(switcher);
    mc.on('swipeleft', () => {
      console.log('left');
      this.dayDown();
    });
    mc.on('swiperight', () => {
      console.log('right');
      this.dayUp();
    });
  });
}
```

You can check this tutorial for more info: https://indepth.dev/gestures-in-an-angular-application/

Comment: I tried putting that code into the zone function but it is behaving the same. To be clear,I have all this code in the NgOnInit function.

Comment: Hmm can you try to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and try to put `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() ` it in the on functions after calling your own functions

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: `constructor(private changeDetectorRef : ChangeDetectorRef ){}` and `mc.on('swipeleft', () => {
      this.dayDown();
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
    });`

Comment: Thank you! That was it. Is this because Angular needed to manually be told about the DOM change because of the way HammerJS works?

Comment: Great! I will update my answer. Yes exactly, HammerJS is a JS library that uses callbacks that are running outside of the Angular zone. So Angular doesn't know that there is a change that needs to run the change detection

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate with **`new Hammer(switcher)`**(H on Capital latter). That's why on methods are not running because they can't find the object.

Comment: The methods are indeed running. I just imported hammer with a lowercase h. But they are being found and called. Something is just breaking somewhere after they get called.